# Dataset to be used to learn NN regressions in classroom experiments

Tags: neural-network, dataset

Can you suggest me datasets with intermediate size of about 1000-10000 to work with neural network regressions in classroom experiments?

It seems that there are much more datasets for classification tasks than for regression tasks.

I know two good datasets:

1. [Boston Housing dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Edelve/data/boston/bostonDetail.html)
2. [Auto MPG Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/auto+mpg)

But they actually seem to be very small. On the other hand, I know other datasets such as [Zillow price](https://www.kaggle.com/c/zillow-prize-1) but they seem to be very large to explore different types of NN regressions in classroom experiments.

Answer (score 1):

May try these two Kaggle datasets -

1. *camnugent/california-housing-prices*
2. *kumarajarshi/life-expectancy-who*

Try your question here - *https://opendata.stackexchange.com/*